# How do I check if the username's length is too long

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, button, while-loop

I have this function that will take 3 parameters, and display it on a label once a button is pressed.

It doesn't work :((

Here is the code for the function:

```
def display_username(firstname, middlename, lastname):  # this function will take 3 parameters, the first name, last name, and middle name of the user

    while i==0  :
        full_name = f"{firstname} {middlename} {lastname}"  # using a formatted string to piece the component of the full name together, defining it as full_name
        label.config( text=f"Hello, {full_name}!")  # configure the label create earlier to display the full_name and with the word 'Hello' in front of it as a greeting message
        label.place(x=300,
                    y=150)  # configure the location of the label to appear acoordingly at those x and y coordinates on the app
        i == 1
        if len(firstname_entry.get(1.0,END)) > 6:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification",'First name is too long!, should be less than 6 characters')
        elif len(middlename_entry.get(1.0,END)) > 10:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Middle name is too long!, should be less than 10 characters')
        elif len(lastname_entry.get(1.0,END)) > 7:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Last name is too long!, should be less than 7 characters')
```

Here is the code for the button:

```
Submit_name = Button(tab1, text='Say Hello:D',command=lambda: display_username(firstname_entry.get(), middlename_entry.get(),lastname_entry.get()))  
# create a button for the using the display username function, displaying the user's information in first->last name order by getting the information typed in the texbox. The command = lambda is used to take the value of first name, middle name and last name to pass it t the display_user function
Submit_name.place(x=400, y=200, width=150, height=30)  
# define the location for the button
```

i want it to check for the length of first, middle and last name and send users a notification saying their name is too long and do nothing until the name is at a desirable. I also want it to take parameters and also use while loops in the function.
IT doesnt work, the terminal said that it took 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: Why do you need the while loop?

Comment: its the AP CSP requirement..:(

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `while loops` together with `tkinter` when you can avoid it! Also next time please provide a minimal reproducible example (a small, working tkinter application that reproduces the error). I could not reproduce your `took 1 positional argument but 3 were given` error with the little of code you provided. What you want can be easily accomplished without any while loop.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def display_username(firstname, middlename,lastname):
    if len(firstname) > 6:
        messagebox.showinfo("Notification",'First name is too long!, should be less than 6 characters')
    if len(middlename) > 10:
        messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Middle name is too long!, should be less than 10 characters')
    if len(lastname) > 7:
        messagebox.showinfo("Notification", 'Last name is too long!, should be less than 7 characters')
    else:
        full_name = f"{firstname}{middlename}{lastname}"
        uname.config(text=f'Hello {full_name}!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    firstname_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    firstname_entry.pack()

    middlename_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    middlename_entry.pack()

    lastname_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    lastname_entry.pack()

    uname = tk.Label(root, text='')
    uname.pack()

    Submit_name = tk.Button(root, text='Say Hello:D',command=lambda: display_username(firstname_entry.get(), middlename_entry.get(),lastname_entry.get()))
    Submit_name.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```